# I am trying to install package fetch

Tags: package-management

```
dam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
  W: Failed ....

adam@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install fetch
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package fetch
```

Comment: There is no `fetch`package in ubuntu.

Comment: Are you trying to install fetchmail?

Comment: sir i am getting error of to install packge fetch during installation of wine

Comment: How are you installing wine?

Comment: downloding tar file from internet in windows then copy it in ubuntu and after extracting using command line and after doing ./ configure and after this getting error

Comment: sir editing mistake..

Answer (score 2):

To install Wine, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Based on your comment that you don't have a internet connection.

Now since you don't have an internet connection, you need to [download Wine 1.6](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/wine/source/1.6/wine-1.6.tar.bz2) file.  Once downloaded, copy the file as is to the Ubuntu system, and then look at [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: sir getting error of pycurl.error: (6, "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'")  during 1st comaand

Comment: Are you running a proxy?  It sounds like an internet connectivity issue.

Comment: I dont have internet connection...it can be possible using windows software that is why I am copying tar file from windows to ubntu

Comment: @mayurMehta If you don't have an Internet connection, then having a working `fetch` command would almost certainly be useless. The `fetch` command, like `wget` (which you should already have) retrieves files from a network server. Unless you are running your own server that has the necessary files, this is probably the Internet. If possible, you should try connect the Ubuntu system to the Internet.

Comment: sir my internet connection run on exe file that's why i want to install wine 1.6 and that's why during installation i am getting an error :)

Answer (score 2):

You said in your question that you are "trying to install package fetch".

fetch is a simple, flexible download tool built on the HTTP Fetcher library. There are other utilities out there that handle HTTP downloads (wget) but a lot of them are intended more for mirroring websites and the like;  fetch allows you to download a file at the command line by basically saying 'fetch URL'. fetch can be downloaded [www.sourceforge.net fetch webpage](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fetch/?source=dlp).

Before installing fetch, the HTTP Fetcher library must be installed.
It can be downloaded from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/http-fetcher/?source=directory

**To install fetch** uncompress the fetch package by running `tar xf fetch-1.0.tar.gz` and from the main fetch directory, type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential    
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

That's it. The program should then be located in `/usr/local/bin/` (unless you specified a different prefix). Note: the above commands are for a basic install, you can also use `checkinstall` to make a .deb package.

Comment: sir I am getting an error of unable to loackate build-essentail package

Comment: @mayurMehta You could also try installing the build-essential package using the Ubuntu Software Center. By the way, in your comment you used `build-essentail`. It should be `build-essential`. And if you don't have an internet connection, then you can't download it, so you also can't install it.

Comment: sir but I don't have an internet conection in ubuntu but it is in windows that's why i have downloaded build-essential.deb file but how to install it?

Comment: @mayurMehta Just double-click on the build-essential.deb file and the Ubuntu Software Center will open and ask you if you want to install it. Then click on **Install** and authenticate with your password to install it using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: i can't install it. when I am installing build-essential_11.4build1_amd64.deb getting error of wrong architecture still i am using amd turior 64 and then i am trying to install build-essential_11.4build1_i386.deb getting error of Dependenci is not satisfiable:g++(>=4:4.3.1) Please help me

Comment: For sure you've got the wrong package. The package you downloaded resembles the package for Ubuntu 10.04 which is already End of Life. Actually it's not even the right package for Ubuntu 10.04. If you're still using Ubuntu 10.04, you should give up and install a supported version of Ubuntu. The latest Long Term Support version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 12.04. Also I think you probably won't be able to get your modem device driver to work using Wine. Your modem probably is not Linux compatible.

Comment: I am using 12. somthing version of ubntu and i have internet connection through software called unicom connection manager

Comment: Yeah, there's the problem. Your Unicom USB Modem is not Linux compatible.

Comment: so that is why iam trying install wine

Comment: W-I-N-E stands for Wine Is Not Emulator. Wine is often no good at emulating hardware environments necessary to install device drivers in Wine.

Comment: wine 1.6 can run this .exe file